# Custom VSTS Build Task to Call PhantomJS Fails to Create Image File

Tags: powershell, azure-pipelines-build-task

I am in the process of writing a custom VSTS extension that (based on parameters) requests a URL and emails the results.  I have all pieces of it functioning properly, except the piece that calls PhantomJS exe.  This is required in order to generate the screenshot, prior to attaching to the email.

The relevant PowerShell code is as follows:

```
Write-Verbose "Run phantomjs with $testingurl"
Start-Process -FilePath "phantomjs.exe" -ArgumentList "screenshot.js",$testingurl
$directory = Get-ScriptDirectory
Get-ChildItem $directory -force
```

I am calling PhantomJS with the relevant parameters, which should create an image in my working directory called 'example.png'.  However, when I then output the contents of the directory, the file is not present.

I have played around with the "scope" of my extension, but it has not helped.  My current scopes are:

```
"scopes": [
    "vso.build_execute",
    "vso.serviceendpoint_manage",
    "vso.code_manage",
    "vso.packaging_manage",
    "vso.release_execute",
    "vso.work_write"
],
```

I also verified that I can create a file if I use the standard PS commandlet:

```
New-Item "$directory\test.txt" -ItemType file
```

I also tried including a blank 'example.png' in my VSIX package that would hopefully be overwritten, but it does not.

So, I'm convinced it's not a write-permission issue.  The VSTS logs give no indication of the call to PhantomJS exe failing.

Are you not allowed to call an exe from a PS script from within a VSTS extension (build task)?  The PS script works correctly locally so I feel this is more of an environment/permission/allowance issue than a code issue on my part.

Comment: You need none of the scopes. A build task has access to the filesystem without any scopes specified. You can call an executable just fine, but it may be that the working directory doesn't match what you're expecting. Try calling `get-command phantomjs.exe` to see if powershell can find it.

Comment: Try using `$PSScriptRoot` to find the location your task was deployed to.

Comment: Will do.  When I output the directory it came back correctly, but I will make your suggestions.

Comment: @jessehouwing, thanks for the suggestions.  It at least lead me in the right direction.  It was a bit odd though how the code ran fine locally with the additional `-Wait` attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue ended up being that the exe was run and my code continued to execute.  I had to add the "-Wait" attribute to my call:

```
Start-Process -FilePath "phantomjs.exe" -ArgumentList "screenshot.js",$testingurl -Wait
```

Since the lines following the call to `phantomjs.exe` requires the execution to finish, the "-Wait" ensures it runs to completion first.